# How to use value selected by Sql Data Source in C# code

Tags: c#, email, sqldatasource, sqldatareader

I am retrieving the email id of the user in SqlDataSource and want to send an email to this email ID. Below is the code for the SQL Data Source.

```
 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="UserDetailsSqlDataSource" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:UserDetailsConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT [LoweredEmail] FROM [vw_aspnet_MembershipUsers] WHERE     ([UserName] = @UserName)">
   <SelectParameters>
        <asp:CookieParameter CookieName="userName" Name="UserName" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Below is the code for sending the email.

```
   MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
   mail.To.Add();
```

I am not getting how to get the email id retrieved in  mail.To.Add();

Comment: Is there "MailMessage.To.Add()" method existing?

Answer (score 1):

You can programmatically call the [`Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.select.aspx) method of a [`SqlDataSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.aspx), which will return one of the following:

- `DataView` when `DataSourceMode` is set to `DataSet`
- `IDataReader` when `DataSourceMode` is set to `DataReader`

Here's an example using a [`SqlDataReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.aspx):

```
var args = System.Web.UI.DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty;
var reader = (SqlDataReader) UserDetailsSqlDataSource.Select(args);

while(reader.Read()) {
   //do something with each returned record, e.g.
   MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
   mail.To.Add(reader["LoweredEmail"].ToString());
}
```

Comment: I am getting following error at while(reader.Read()) line .

System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: can you update your original post with the new code you are trying? I'll need some context

Answer (score 1):

Try this, you may modify the code to pass the parameter:

```
        string temp = string.Empty;
        string cmdText = "SELECT [LoweredEmail] FROM [vw_aspnet_MembershipUsers] WHERE     ([UserName] = @UserName)"
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, conn))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@UserName, UserName);
                using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while(reader.Read())
                    {
                        temp = reader.GetValue(0).ToString(); // email ID
                    }
                }
            }
            conn.Close();
```

Comment: I am getting the email ID from SQL Data Source and then trying to feed that value in To field to send an email. Below is the code that I am writing for this.

    var args = System.Web.UI.DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty;
SqlDataReader reader   =(SqlDataReader)UserDetailsSqlDataSource.Select(args);

            reader.Read(); // I am getting error on this line that "System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object"
            String temp = reader.GetValue(0).ToString(); 
  mail.To.Add(temp);

Comment: Sorry: it should be while(reader.Read()) etc. I already updated the code.